# Laravel blade-ui-icons render issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

JavaScript code is not working for getting icon from blade template that already rendered with defer attribute.

Hi, I am going to work with laravel blade-icons (https://github.com/blade-ui-kit/blade-icons). I'm successfully rendered icons in the blade template using the blade icon component. But when I am trying to get an icon from javaScript using the example code in Git Hub doc (https://github.com/blade-ui-kit/blade-icons#deferring-icons) it does not show anything. Here is my example code:::

Blade Code:::

```xml
<section hidden class="hidden">
    <x-icon name="iconsax-bro-key" defer='bro-key'></x-icon>
</section>
<section class="iconplace"></section>
```

Javascript Code::::

```js
var loadIcon = <svg><use href="#icon-bro-key"></use></svg>;
$(".iconplace").html(loadIcon);
console.log(loadIcon); // Given the systex error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<')

var svg = document.createElement("svg");
var use = document.createElement("use");
use.setAttribute("href","#icon-bro-key");
svg.appendChild(use);
document.querySelector(".iconplace").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin',svg); // Not working - [object HTMLUnknownElement]
console.log(svg);

var iconStore = `<svg><use href="#icon-bro-key"></use></svg>`;
$(".iconplace").html(iconStore); // Not working - didn't show anything
console.log(iconStore);
```